# Code Contracts at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts, production

As far as I read in a nutshell book, code contracts could degrade the runtime performance.

Is it possible to disable code contracts in production?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [user manual](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf) explains this in a fair amount of detail - there are all kinds of options you can have. Each build configuration can have different settings for which contracts are checked at execution time, and it's not an "all or nothing" choice - you can enforce all, some or none of the contracts, based on settings which can be tweaked in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 12):

I have my favorite options described [on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2011/01/simple-and-easy-code-contracts.html).

To summarize:

- In Release mode, I recommend unchecking Perform Runtime Contract Checking but selecting to Build the Contract Reference Assembly. This will place Preconditions in a separate dll which your clients can optionally use (if they check Call-site Requires Checking), but removes all overhead if they don't check that option.
- In Debug mode, set Perform Runtime Contract Checking to Full.

Some people prefer Preconditions to be included in their Release build. This is particularly useful if distributing via NuGet because [they don't support Code Contract dlls](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/263). For my NuGet packages, I'm migrating towards including Preconditions in the Release builds, but also having a separate download for a "Release without Preconditions" build.

Answer (score 8):

The performance difference is quite small and will not affect your code in a noticeable way. Unless you are developing some real-time stock trading system, I seriously wouldn't even worry about it.

As far as disabling the code in Production, I would far rather have the added protection of Code Contracts instead of some possibly obscure error.  An error in the code contract will tell you exactly where and why the Contract was violated as opposed to having to dig down in some deep call-stack just because some bad data was passed in 5 levels up the call-stack tree.

@svanryckeghem and @Stephen Cleary:
If you are using or are planning to use `Contract.Requires<TException>` and do not enable 'Runtime Contract Checking', you'll get a runtime failure about the IL rewriter (ccrewrite.exe) needing to be bound to the usage of Code Contracts.  You will then be required to enable Runtime Contract Checking to get this to work.

IMHO, the use of `Contract.Requires<TException>()` is far more useful than `Contract.Requires()` since you have control over the type of exception thrown.

Comment: `Contract.Requires<TException>()`, I disagree that this is more useful, I think it's more of a legacy thing- I don't use it at all.  The contract requires are almost all argument exceptions of one sort or another and the boolean condition is sufficient information; if you design things appropriately.  `Contracts` aren't just another way of doing `Exception`s, they require a different approach.

Comment: The operative phrase in your comment is "...almost all argument exceptions...".  I don't want to setup contracts based on an "almost". If I can guarantee that they are all of the same type of Exception, then yes using the Contract.Requires<TException>() is redundant.  However, this is not guaranteed and I'd rather cover all scenarios - especially the edge-cases - otherwise your contracts become nothing more than speculations.

Answer (score 4):

In your project properties, go to Code Contract, select the "Release" Configuration and uncheck runtime checking.